# Trouble installing scala on a mac

Tags: macos, scala

I installed brew and installed java, then tried installing Scala using the following command. I got the error

```
brew cask install scala
Error: Cask 'scala' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists. Did you mean one of:
scala-ide
Error: Install incomplete.
```

Then I tried using this command brew install Caskroom/cask/scala-ide. Then I installed spark and SBT. Now the issue is I cannot open Scala. I can open spark, but not Scala. But brew confirms that Scala is installed.

I try this command

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/scala-ide
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
getdns                                                                                                    
==> brew cask install Caskroom/cask/scala-ide 
Warning: Cask 'scala-ide' is already installed.

To re-install scala-ide, run:
brew cask reinstall scala-ide
```

How do I open Scala if it is already installed.

Comment: scala-ide is not the same as scala. Try `brew update` then `brew install scala` (not `brew cask`, just `brew`)

Comment: Thank you, that has done the trick.